# Angularjs $q Factory issue, Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been trying to make a re-usable auto search in anuglarjs factory. 
Here is my Code. But unfortunately getting the error: "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined". Tried to search on Google and here in stack overflow but fail to fix it.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict'
  angular.module('App').factory('LoadFormActivity', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {

    function NGAutoCompleteSearch(url, val) {

      var def = $q.defer();

      $http.get(url, {
        params: {
          searchvalue: val
        }
      }).then(function(response) {
        debugger
        def.resolve(response);
      }, function(response) {
        debugger
        def.reject(response);
      });

      return def.promise;
    };

    return {
      NGAutoCompleteSearch: NGAutoCompleteSearch

    };


  }]);

})();

//Controller.

(function() {

  'use strict'
  angular.module('App').controller('ServicesMasterCtrl', ['$timeout', '$scope', '$filter', '$http', 'NGAutoComplete', 'LoadFormActivity', function($timeout, $scope, $filter, $http, NGAutoComplete, LoadFormActivity) {

    $scope.FormService.AutoSearch = {};

    $scope.FormService.AutoSearch.Search = function(id) {

      LoadFormActivity.NGAutoCompleteSearch('/Assets/AssetsAPI/GetServiceRecord', id).then(
        function(data) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        });
    };
  }]);
})();
```

```html
<div ng-controller="ServicesMasterCtrl">
  <md-autocomplete md-items="item in FormService.AutoSearch.Search(id)" md-selected-item="FormService.AutoSearch.selectedItem" md-search-text-change="FormService.AutoSearch.SearchChanged(id)" md-search-text="id" md-min-length="2" md-delay="500" placeholder="Search service by id or name"
    md-item-text="item.id" md-no-cache="true">
    <md-item-template>
      <span class="item-title">Id:{{item.id}}                           </span><span class="item-metadata">
    <span class="item-metastat">Service: <strong> {{item.servicename}} </strong></span>
      <md-icon md-svg-icon="octicon-repo.svg"></md-icon><span class="item-metastat" ng-if="!!item.montlyrental">MonthlyRental: <strong> {{item.montlyrental}} </strong></span><span class="item-metastat" ng-if="!!item.activationdate">ActiveDate: <strong> {{item.activationdate |  ConvertToDate | date: 'dd-MMM-yyyy'}} </strong></span></span>
    </md-item-template>
    <md-not-found>No matching items found...</md-not-found>
  </md-autocomplete>
</div>
```

Can someone please help me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simplify the `LoadFormActivity` service. There is no need for that extra promise at the bottom.

```
function NGAutoCompleteSearch(url, val) {

    return $http.get(url, { params: {searchvalue: val} });

}
```

Comment: **James**, I still get error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined. I don't know whether its the error caused by angular material autocomplete or my $http request. If know anyone, please let me know here. Thanks

Comment: I suggest logging out the values of `loadFormActivity.`and `loadFormActivity.NGAutoCompleteSearch` in the controller